# Insert each column from one table to it's own row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (SAMPLE) with about 20 columns and thousands of rows.  I have another table (SAMPLE_DETAIL) with 2 columns (DETAIL_NAME, DETAIL_VALUE).  What i would like to do is insert all of the columns from SAMPLE into SAMPLE_DETAIL as each it's own row using the column name as SAMPLE_DETAIL.DETAIL_NAME and it's value as SAMPLE_DETAIL.DETAIL_VALUE.

**SAMPLE Table**

```
ID, TEXT_ID, DESCRIPTION, LOG_DATE, LOG_BY
1, SAMPLE_01, AA, 07-02-14, SW
2, SAMPLE_02, AB, 07-02-14, RC
3, SAMPLE_03, AC, 07-02-14, MH
4, SAMPLE_04, AD, 07-02-14, RS
```

**TO**

**SAMPLE_DETAIL Table**

```
DETAIL_NAME, DETAIL_VALUE
ID, 1
TEXT_ID, SAMPLE_01
DESCRIPTION, AA
LOG_DATE, 07-02-14
LOG_BY, SW

ID, 2
TEXT_ID, SAMPLE_02
DESCRIPTION, AB
LOG_DATE, 07-02-14
LOG_BY, RC

ID, 2
TEXT_ID, SAMPLE_03
DESCRIPTION, AC
LOG_DATE, 07-02-14
LOG_BY, MH

ID, 3
TEXT_ID, SAMPLE_04
DESCRIPTION, AD
LOG_DATE, 07-02-14
LOG_BY, RS
```

I hope my example helps explain my problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is with `union all`:

```
insert into sample_detail(detail_name, detail_value)
    select 'id', id from sample union all
    select 'text_id', text_id from sample union all
    select 'description', description from sample union all
    select 'log_date', log_date from sample union all
    select 'log_by', log_by from sample;
```

Because everything is stored as strings, you might want specific conversion for dates (using `convert()` say), but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you!  That was WAY easier then what I was dabbling with.